# Why do some Linux utilities output Unicode (when it is not expected)?

Tags: locale, unicode, utilities

While building a tool that reads command output I realized that some Linux utilities output Unicode characters when I didn't really expect them to do so. For instance, `find` uses `‘` (as opposed to the ASCII `'`) as a quote character in its error output:

```
~ > find /root
/root
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
```

The same goes for `g++`:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:2:9: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
  return foo;
         ^~~
main.cpp:2:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘bool’
  return foo;
         ^~~
         bool
```

Is this something to do with my system locale? Or is this something else? Output of `localectl`:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_ZA.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=en_ZA:en
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
```

Comment: Yes it uses quotes instead of apostrophes. And Unix has been using unicode for a while. utf-8 is the default coding. You can downgrade to `C` local, if you don't like it. What problem are you trying to solve? Do these unicode characters get in the way of some text processing. I suspect this is the real question.

Comment: The utilities are GNU (and sometimes other) utilities, not Linux utilities.

Comment: _"... when I didn't really expect them to do so"_ - Why not? Those are proper quote characters, used for, well, quotes like in your example. ASCII `'` is legacy inherited from when typewriters were too primitive to carry multiple quote symbols. We've left those limitations behind us, mostly.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The Unicode characters are not a problem at all, I was just surprised to see a utility like find output "fancy" characters. Not planning on downgrading the locale, the question was just a matter of interest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has everything to do with your system locale as it describes how utilities should output locale specific symbols and their combinations, e.g. `‘’` instead of `""`.

If you don't want this, use a different locale, e.g. `C` which is as standard and pristine as possible:

```bsh
$ LC_CTYPE=C find /root
/root
find: '/root': Permission denied
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to actually check these rules for a locale? I tried seeing what I can find out with the `locale` (`locale -k LC_CTYPE`) command but I'm not seeing anything related specifically to quoting

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=localedata/locales/en_ZA;hb=HEAD - inherits en_GB and iso14651_t1

Comment: @kobus-v-schoor the quotes shouldn't be your only concern. Even if   the message was output by the exact program version you were expecting the output could be in French, Chinese or GReek...

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks, was interesting to read through the locale files, just what I needed